# callling deployed contract xyz public payable function from deployed contract abc with hexdata in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

In deployed contract with address abc I have:

```
function CallContract(address tosend,uint amount,bytes hexdata,uint zgas) public payable {
       tosend.call.gas(zgas).value(amount)(hexdata);
}
```

In web3 I have

```
await AbcContract.methods
.CallContract(this.state.tosend,amounttowei,web3.utils.fromAscii(data),gas)
.send({
    from:accounts[0]
});
```

In the deployed contract with address xyz I have:

```
   uint public somevar;
   uint public anothervar;

function DoSomething() public payable {
    uint somevar = 1;
}

function DoSomethingAgain(uint justanumber) public payble {
    uint anothervar = justanumber;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

In etherscan I get

> Although one or more Error Occurred [Out of gas] Contract Execution Completed

Comment: Hi jim, can you please provide the full source of the Smart Contract, the address, and network you have deployed the contract to? That will greatly help with debugging your issue.

Comment: How do you generate hexdata?

Comment: Using contract.methods.functionhere().encodeABI(); via web3